# update jquery select2 available choices for multiple instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2

I have two jquery select2 instances that have the same options and the same class
I want that each time I select an option in one select2 instance it becomes not available in both instances

```
<select class="select2-element" multiple="multiple"> //instance 1
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    ...
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>

<select class="select2-element" multiple="multiple"> //instance 2
    <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
    ...
    <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
</select>
```

**EDIT**
For simplicity I mentioned that I have two select elements, but in reality I have x elements generated dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to avoid that all the instances get the same selected items like @blubberbo mentioned,I gave each element an id and I changed the way to retrieve selected options.
I used the generated classes by select2.js as selectors to get the selected options from the select2 element.

```
    $('#Save').click(function () {
        $('.select2-element').each(function () {
            var instance = $(this).attr('id');
            $('#s2id_' + instance + ' li.select2-search-choice div').each(function () {
                alert($(this).attr('id'));
            });
        });
    });
```

the div element under li.select2-search-choice doesn't have an id attribute so I added that to the select2.js like this:

```
choice.find("div").replaceWith("<div id="+id+" >"+formatted+"</div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

What about giving the second `<select>` tag an id such as `<select id="changeSelect"...`

and adding adding a listener in jQuery like:

```
$('select2-element').on('change', function() {
  var selectValue = $(this).val(); 
  $('#changeSelect').val( selectValue);
});
```

I might also suggest getting rid of the `select2-element` class on the first `<select>` tag in order to prevent the second one from dynamically selecting on itself

Comment: Thank you, I only changed the $('#changeSelect') by $('.select2-element') and I got the behavior that I was looking for.

Comment: That's great, but I should warn you to be careful with that. If you are setting the value with `$('.select2-element').val( selectValue);`, you are targetting ALL the elements with class `select2-element`, not just the second one. In this instance, it might not interfere with what you want, meaning it might look as though it is behaving correctly, but keep in mind that it's actually targetting ALL of them, not just the one you want it to. I would use different classes, ids or more intricate JS code in order to only target the one you want. If you create more, you might run into trouble

Comment: that's right all the select elements got the same selected items, so I tried another workaround to get them properly, I posted a new answer.